# how to add a label to combined rows in latex?

Tags: latex, tabular

```html
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
AGE & Percentage \\ 
  \hline
19-24 & 6\% \\ 
  25-34 & 18\% \\ 
  35-44 & 24\% \\ 
  45-54 & 36\% \\ 
  55-64 & 7\% \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want to remove the label "Age" and add it to the center left of the first table, like the last table.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tabularray` package, this make it easy to merge multiple cells into one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{Xcc}
  \hline
\SetCell[r=5]{} Age of ...&19-24 & 6\% \\ 
&  25-34 & 18\% \\ 
&  35-44 & 24\% \\ 
&  45-54 & 36\% \\ 
&  55-64 & 7\% \\ 
   \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how to fit the table to the page margins as in the second image I posted?

Comment: and can I adjust the second column to be at the middle ?

Comment: @y.eska With so much space between the age and the percentages, it won't be easy for the eye to stay in a line.

Comment: yes, I think that age ranges are extreme right though. Is there a way to narrow the spaces as in the table in last image?

Comment: @y.eska `\begin{tblr}{XQ[1.5cm]c}` would move them a bit further left without going all the way to the middle

Answer (score 0):

Another way, with similar output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
%\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcc}
\toprule
\multirow{4}{*}{Age of the respondents}
& $\le$ 20 & 29\%\\
& 21-25    & 65\%\\
& 26-30    &  7\%\\
& $>$ 30   &  2\%\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]